# matplotlib .plot function drawing multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So i made a code to compare some distribution fits using matplotlib and scypy. thats the code:

```
    listvar = [sessioninterval, playtime, sessiontime, pausetime] 
listnames1 = ["Sessioninterval", "Playtime", "Sessiontime", "Pausetime"]

expfit=  []
normfit = []
lognormfit = []

for p in listvar:
    expfit.append( stats.expon.fit(p, floc = 0))
    normfit.append(stats.norm.fit(p))
    lognormfit.append(stats.lognorm.fit(p))

for q in range(4):
    plt.hist(listvar[q], bins = len(listvar[q]), normed = True, cumulative = True, histtype = "step", color = "black", label = "EDF")
    plt.plot(listvar[q],stats.expon.cdf(listvar[q],*expfit[q]) , color = 'blue',label = "Exponencial Fit: " + str(expfit[q]))
    plt.plot(listvar[q],stats.norm.cdf(listvar[q], *normfit[q]), '-',color =  'red', label = "Normal Fit: "+ str(normfit[q]))
    plt.plot(listvar[q],stats.lognorm.cdf(listvar[q], *lognormfit[q]), '-',color =  'green', label = "Log-Normal Fit: " + str(lognormfit[q]) )
    plt.title("Probability Fit: " + str(listnames1[q]))
    plt.xlabel("Value")
    plt.ylabel("Probability")
    plt.xlim(min(listvar[q]), max(listvar[q]))
    plt.ylim(0,1)
    plt.legend( bbox_to_anchor = (1.05,-0.1), fontsize = 10)
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.24)
    plt.savefig("Probability_" + listnames1[q] +".png")
    plt.clf()
```

and this is an example of the results

[image]

why is this happening? thanks!

Comment: Your points (`listvar[q]`) are not sorted. Either sort them first, or use plt.scatter to plot them without connecting the points with lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplot requires the point to be sorted out before plotting.

What you are seeing is that it is connecting the unsorted points. It's not plotting multiple times.